# How to access Xcode database from iPhone app

Tags: ios, iphone, database, xcode

This is my first iPhone app. I'm using Xcode 7.3.

In the app I used [this tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_4_iPhone_Application) to create an sql database using the app (when the user gives permission by pressing a button, it creates the .db file).

Now I would like to know how I can download the database from the app.

Here is why:

The app will be downloaded on someone's device (not via the app store). It is supposed to collect data from a wearable device and store it in the database.

However I don't know how to access that data later on when I have the user's phone. Apparently the db lives in

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/###/Documents
```

I read that one method is "jailbreaking." But I have never done that and this is not my phone I'm dealing with, it's a client's, so I don't feel comfortable hacking it. Is there another way? Possibly through the terminal (this is how I did it with the android app, using adb)?

Or is there another way I can go about saving the database so that it is accessible/retrievable?

Comment: You need to build access to the DB file into your app, so that it could "call home" and upload the data when you instruct it to do so.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Is there a way to save the db in another directory that is accessible? Sorry, this is my first iPhone app. I don't use an iphone

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is correct but incomplete :

Once you have download the Container, the extension is .xcappdata, so you need to right-click on it and select show the package.

Then browse into /library/Application support/ to find your database in .sqlite

Answer (score -1):

You can try to connect the device to your Mac, then in XCode, go to Window, Devices, select your device and app bundle and click "Download Container...".
[image]

To see the database, you could use [SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/).